# Make Material UI Container Component responsive

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want the Container Component have a different maxWidth Prop depending on Theme Breakpoints.
Is there anything built-in for this or how should I do that?

Comment: if u like my answer u can mark it as the answer

Comment: yup now that I have also implemented it I will

Answer (score 3, accepted):

u can use `useTheme` and `useMediaQuery` hooks to do it easily:

```
import { useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import useMediaQuery from '@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery';

function CustomContainer(props){
    const theme = useTheme();
    const matches = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up('sm'));
    return <Container maxWidth={matches ? 'lg' : 'sm'} >
    {/* your components */} 
    </Container>

}
```